# Powershell Script To Get Timestamps of Nested files

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, powershell, automation

We have a situation with with our SQL Server database backups.

Data:

1. Actually our DBA has set backups of website databases to every 4 hours
2. The backup of each website database is created every 4 hours and it contains 4 files (with `.bak`) extension.
3. Folder hierarchy of these backup files are as follows:

   ```
   \\folder\sub-folder\(4 X Files).bak
   ```

PROBLEM we have is that we have to check in each "sub-folder" if the 4 (four) `.bak` files are created after every four 4 hours manually.

Can somebody help with the creation of the powershell script which can :

1. Generate the list of the web sites (subfolder name) in which 4 new files are not created for the latest timestamp.
2. Email us the list

Thanks in advance.

Saeed

Comment: Why don't you try and create the script, and then ask for help if you have any trouble with it?

Comment: If I could make it myself why would I be asking :D

Comment: I have created following but it is not getting me what I want:
$folder='B:\sub-folder\Catfish_test'
$Clients = Import-CSV C:\test\backups.csv

$Files = Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse -include @("*.bak") | Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date )} | select name 

$Clients | ForEach-Object { 
    $Client = $_
    $ClientCheck = $Files | Where-Object {$_ -like $Client}
    If (-not $ClientCheck) { 
        Write-Warning "$Client is missing!"
    }Else{
        Write-Output $ClientCheck
    }
} | out-file C:\test\result.txt

Comment: What is the script giving you instead? Error message? Undesired behaviour? Edit your post, paste your code there well formatted, and describe the issue you have with the script

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Hi I have posted a new question couldn't post the code correctly. please answer in following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47866318/powershell-script-to-get-timestamps-of-nested-files-new