# PowerShell Script To Get Timestamps of Nested files (new)

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, powershell, automation

Our DBA has set backups of website databases to every 4 hours.
The backup of each website database is created every 4 hours and it contains 4 files (with .bak) extension.
Folder hierarchy of these backup files are as follows:

\\folder\sub-folder(4 X Files).bak

The problem we have is that we have to check in each "sub-folder" if the 4 (four) .bak files are created after every four 4 hours manually.

Can somebody help with the creation of a PowerShell script that can:

- Generate the list of the web sites (subfolder name) in which 4 new files are not created for the latest timestamp.
- Email us the list.

Following is the script I am using for this but it only gives part of the required stuff:

```
$folder = 'B:\sub-folder\Catfish_test'

$Clients = Import-Csv C:\test\backups.csv

$Files = Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -Include @("*.bak") |
         Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date)} |
         select name 

$Clients | ForEach-Object {
    $Client = $_
    $ClientCheck = $Files | Where-Object {$_ -like $Client}
    if (-not $ClientCheck) { 
        Write-Warning "$Client is missing!"
    } else {
        Write-Output $ClientCheck
    }
} | Out-File C:\test\result.txt
```

Comment: What about the code you posted isn't working the way you expected?

Comment: Please dont ask the same Question multiple Times.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833006/powershell-script-to-get-timestamps-of-nested-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Script To Get Timestamps of Nested files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833006/powershell-script-to-get-timestamps-of-nested-files)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  This code is comparing the names in the .csv file and the names of "Subfolders" .
and letting me know the missing "subfolder" 
What I want is , 

I need it to generate the list of the web sites (subfolder name) in which 4 new files are not created for the latest timestamp.
each subfolder contains .bak files , I need to confirm if all the four .bak files  are created inside each subfolder of latest timestamp.

Comment: @Paxz I wasn't able to put up code correctly in the previous question so I had to create this question.

Comment: Then please edit the question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I closed the other question, because this one is more complete and it would be more hassle to close this one and edit the other. However, next time please do as Paxz suggested and edit your original question. There's a link "edit" right below each question for this very purpose.

Comment: Your directory structure still isn't clear to me. Your code snippet has a path `B:\sub-folder\Catfish_test`, but before that you talk about a path `\\folder\sub-folder`. Which is the `sub-folder`? Please give us a consistent description. Also, can there be more than one backup-set of 4 files in any given folder?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers please consider
'B:\'   as  =  '\\folder\'

sub-folder is the folder within the root/parent directory
yes there are more than one backup set of 4 files

thanks.